# Does native array.js make me slower

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-ui, combobox, autocomplete

So, I have ~600 companies in `<select>` list  that is "widgetized" with jQueryUI autocomplete combobox. It's a slowest part of my page, when I try to find string for any time except first one.

I've start to profile JS perfomance with Chrome developer tools and find that the most awful part is `sort` method that browser call out of `native array.js`.

That is the picture how I've got idea about it:

[image: My code profiling]

~11,5 seconds to render out dropdown list on last selected input value? What should I do and what kind of example to provide my experience? Help me to improve that terrible thing!

**UPD**:

It's looks like "each time I've opening dropdown list it handle something one more time and make it twice, but I'm not sure that it's a sorting or something else except native Array.js method sort with `g.nodeType.g.documentLement.l` function:

[image: g.nodeType.g.documentLement.l example]

**UPD**:
My browser is Chrome 60.0.3112.90 and JavaScript V8 6.0.286.52
I will try non-minified jquery-1.12.4.js to find out why does there is idle moments appear between compareDocumentPosition property calling inside jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've stopped slow UI-flow investigation when my library was updated and today I've received negative feedback "slow list opening UI" again. I was surprised until remember that production and development environment has little difference.
— Local developer have used non-minified library files and
— Prodcution has minified library

When I've checked all libraries we used I find jQuery UI. Even last but minified version slow down combobox list render in a manner I've described above.

Have no idea why but now we using non-minified jQ-UI and problem was resolved.